# Prevent UnAuhtorize Node to Join Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra, authorization, cql, cassandra-2.0

I'm using Apache Cassandra 2.1.2 and create 5 nodes cluster.
in `cassandra.yaml` config file, authorizer & authenticator properties are set to `CassandraAuthorizer` and `PasswordAuthenticator`.

It's works prefect but when some of these nodes config file changed to connect without authorization, this node can query all keyspaces and read all secure data easily!

What can do to secure Cassandra keyspaces and data from being accessed from authorized client (node)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned about config files being reset, you should really consider using configuration management software like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) to keep your configuration in sync between the nodes in your cluster.

I'd also strongly recommend setting up [node-to-node encryption](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureSSLNodeToNode_t.html) and set up a trust store on your cassandra nodes that only allows other nodes to join the ring if they provide a certificate that is trusted.

This way you can't have unauthorized nodes joining your ring that you don't know about.   Also, chances are if your config files are changed, the server_encryption_options will be invalidated as well and your node won't be able to connect.

If you are concerned about securing your cluster.  I'd also recommend using [client-to-node encryption](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureSSLClientToNode_t.html) when using authorization as without SSL the credentials are passed in the clear when a client connects.